# How to skip first/current request in newman through data file?

Tags: postman, newman

I have a column called 'value' in my data.csv file. When its value is 1, I want to run only the request with ID "1" (and skip request ID "2") and when it is 2, request ID "2" should run (and skip request ID "1").

I tried the following already:

Collection pre-request script:

```
var valueFromData = pm.iterationData.get("value");

if(valueFromData === 1) {
    postman.setNextRequest("1");
}

if(valueFromData === 2) {
    postman.setNextRequest("2");
}
```

Request "1" pre-request script:

```
var valueFromData = pm.iterationData.get("value");

if(valueFromData === 1) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}

if(valueFromData === 2) {
    postman.setNextRequest("2");
}
```

Request "2" pre-request script:

```
var valueFromData = pm.iterationData.get("value");

if(valueFromData === 1) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}

if(valueFromData === 2) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Actual result:

When value = 1, RequestId "1" is called. RequestId "2" is skipped due to the next request being set as null. This is fine.

When value = 2, RequestId "1" is not expected to be called. But it is called! RequestId "2" is called after that.

Expected result:

When value = 1, only RequestId "1" should be called. RequestId "2" should be skipped

When value = 2, only RequestId "2" should be called. RequestId "1" should be skipped

In short, the first request of collection is always called irrespective of setting next requests. May I know how to skip the first/current request conditionally please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method name is setNextRequest()

I allways use it in test segment to set next request, not current in pre-request segment.

My proposition:

- delete collection script as pointless
- add empty/neutral request "0"
- set next request here:

  ```
  if(valueFromData === 1) {
      postman.setNextRequest("1");
  }

  if(valueFromData === 2) {
      postman.setNextRequest("2");
  }
  ```
- in test script in "1" set:

  ```
  if(valueFromData === 1) {
      postman.setNextRequest(null); }
  ```
- delete script inside "2" as pointless

This solution isn't elegnt but should work.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. What would be the url of the empty request? I could not leave it blank. I tried with http://localhost. Is there any other way to not record this empty request in the result?